# Excluding subdirectory from future search

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wondering how can i set my directory to exclude a certain subdirectory from my search

basically if the shellscript is launched with `./myprogram -exclude [FOLDER]`

i want to exclude the subdirectory from all my future searches

let's say we have a test directory named TEST

> TEST
>
> ---
>
> > subdirectory/file3.tex
>   > file1.txt
>   > file2.pdf

so my program looks something like this

```
#!bin/bash
if [ $1 == "-exclude" ]
then
  DIR="$PWD"
  EXCLUDED="$2"
  if [ -d "$EXCLUDED" ]
  then
    DIR=`find $DIR -type d ! -path "$EXCLUDED"`
    # this actually works will only write the root directory TEST
  fi

  #However, when I do then
  FILES=`find "$DIR" -type f`
  echo "$FILES"
  # I get also the "subdirectory included which should not be happening"
```

Any idea to set it, so I don't have to manually change every find command to complicated -pruning and -o and just use my DIR that excludes the specified subdirectory?

Technically I know why this is happening, that's because the DIR is set to root directory again since `find $DIR -type d ! -path $EXCLUDED` returns root (TEST) only, since  so when i use `find $DIR -type f` it will execute the command `find TEST -type f`, which obviously will include even the directory i wanted to exclude, but somehow i'm looking if it's possible to somehow change the path of DIR to exclude the subdirectory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i found the answer, not exactly what I wanted, but i guess with the find command, we can modify the directory instead to

```
EXCLUDED="*/""$2""/*"
```

and set  `FILES=$(find "$DIR" -type f ! -path "$EXCLUDED")` and it works